# How to resolve the data competition for completion Flag when waiting for a thread pools complete?

Tags: multithreading, performance, thread-safety, threadpool

I have write a simple thread pool, but it seems that have a great competition of the completion flag variable, the thread worker like that:

```
class ThreadWorker {  
private:
    uint32_t m_id;  // worker id
    EasyThreadPool *m_pool;  // thread pool

public:
    ThreadWorker(EasyThreadPool *pool, const uint32_t id) : m_pool(pool), m_id(id) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        while (!m_pool->m_shutdown) {
            if (!m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].is_queue_busy.load()) {
                continue;
            }
            // if the queue is not empty
            if (m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].iNow != m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].iLast) {
                Scheduler::Event *e = &*m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].iNow;
                // process the event
                e->invoke();
                m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].iNow++;
            } else {
                m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].is_queue_busy.store(false);
                m_pool->m_all_queues_busy.fetch_and(~(1 << m_id));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and a part of the code for the thread pool:

```
struct EventsQueue {
    std::vector<Scheduler::Event>::iterator iFirst;
    std::vector<Scheduler::Event>::iterator iLast;
    std::vector<Scheduler::Event>::iterator iNow;
    std::atomic<bool> is_queue_busy;
    EventsQueue()
    {
        is_queue_busy.store(false);
    }
};

class ThreadPool {
private:
    bool m_shutdown;  // is thread pool shutdown

    const uint32_t m_threads_nums;

    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;  // the thread worker array

    std::vector<EventsQueue> m_local_work_queues;  // thread local tasks queue

    std::atomic_uint_fast64_t m_all_queues_busy;  // a bit map for judge all threads are busy
```

I found that the performance of the program is unpredictable, performance gap of up to 40%. The completion time of my program is from 72s to 120s. But I found that if I add an operation of std::this_thread::yield in the thread worker, like that:

```
ThreadWorker(EasyThreadPool *pool, const uint32_t id) : m_pool(pool), m_id(id) {}

void operator()()
{
    while (!m_pool->m_shutdown) {
        if (!m_pool->m_local_work_queues[m_id].is_queue_busy.load()) {
            // this extra operation
            std::this_thread::yield();
            continue;
        }
```

The performance will be stable at 80 seconds. It puzzles me a lot. I don't have much experience with multithreaded programming. How to explain this phenomenon and solve it? o.O Thanks a lot~